# VBA using a ListBox to apply selections to a Module

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA, so thanks in advance for the advice. I am just dabbling to help out a friend to make his work less repetitive in my free time.

I created a GUI that has 2 ListBoxes that contain the names of the worksheets in the excel file.  The left ListBox contains the available worksheets and the right ListBox is the list of worksheets the user chooses to perform the analysis on with the ability to move the names between the 2 ListBoxes.  I am trying to link the GUI to my Module I created that performs the actual analysis.  Once it is linked, I need the Selections that are made in the GUI to become an array that can be looped through in the Module.  I am missing a few pieces, so bear with me please.

[image: Example GUI]

---

Submit Button Code:

```
Dim Size As Integer 
Size = Me. ListBox2 . ListCount - 1 
ReDim Selection(0 To Size) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Size 
    Selection (i) = Me.ListBox2.ItemData(i) 
Next i 

Unload GUI
```

---

The Area in the Module that I want to implement the Selection:

```
'Only performs copy/paste actions on the worksheets that aren't named "Summary".
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook. Worksheets 
        If sh.Name < > DestSh.Name Then 
'Sets the Range you want to Copy from the source Worksheets. This range is the set of cells with data in it.
            Set CopyRng = sh. UsedRange
```

The goal is to read the Selections from the GUI, locate the sheet that the Selections are named after and link the selections to the "sh" variable somehow.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do with the sheets in the listbox?

Comment: The selected sheets (the ones that are in the Summary Worksheet ListBox) are copied and reformatted in to a "Summary" sheet that is created. Once the data from each sheet is on the summary page, some basic operations are performed on the data then formatted for display uses.  I have the code working fine without the GUI. I just need the Selections from the GUI to translate to tell the main module which sheets to look for.

Comment: Where is `Selections` declared? is it a Global variable or a userform variable?

Comment: I have it as Global variable in the main module separate from the userform

Comment: I've posted an answer. Take a look at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already referencing `sh` as a Worksheet variable in your code, while the `Selections` array holds strings, I believe the simplest way would be to shift the `For..Each` statement to:

```
For Each sel_item In Selection
```

and add the line:

```
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sel_item)
```

You will, of course, also need to edit the `Next sh` statement to `Next sel_item`, and add a `Dim sel_item as Variant`

---

In other words, the beginning of the loop section will look like:

```
'Only performs copy/paste actions on the worksheets that aren't named "Summary".
    For Each sel_item In Selection
        Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sel_item)
        If sh.Name < > DestSh.Name Then 
'Sets the Range you want to Copy from the source Worksheets. This range is the set of cells with data in it.
            Set CopyRng = sh. UsedRange
```

Instead of this (original):

```
'Only performs copy/paste actions on the worksheets that aren't named "Summary".
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook. Worksheets 
        If sh.Name < > DestSh.Name Then 
'Sets the Range you want to Copy from the source Worksheets. This range is the set of cells with data in it.
            Set CopyRng = sh. UsedRange
```

Comment: This solved one of the main underlying problems.  I also found that there was an issue with Private/Public Subs and Variables. I got it all Ironed Out. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

## Delimited Cell Expansion

First adjust the values in the constants section and then read through the whole comments because there might be some issues you wouldn't expect. You can use it on any column containing commas as delimiters, so in your case you can use it on the Base column, too.

```
Sub DelimitedCellExpansion()

  Const cVntWsSource As String = "Sheet1"   ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cStrSourceFirst As String = "A1"    ' Source First Cell Range of Data
  Const cVntSplit As Variant = "D"          ' Source Column Letter/Number
  Const cVntWsTarget As String = "Sheet2"   ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cStrTargetFirst As String = "B1"    ' Target First Cell Range of Data

  Const cStrSep  As String = ",,,|,,|, ,"   ' Wrong Separators

  Dim vntSrc As Variant       ' Source Array
  Dim vntSep As Variant       ' Separator Array
  Dim vntSplitData As Variant ' Split Data Array
  Dim vntSplit As Variant     ' Split Array
  Dim vntCol As Variant       ' Target Column Array
  Dim vntTgt As Variant       ' Target Array

  Dim intCol As Integer       ' Source Array Target Column
  Dim lng1 As Long            ' Source Array Target Column Rows Count(er)
  Dim int1 As Integer         ' Separator Array Strings Counter
  Dim lng2 As Long            ' Target Array Rows Count(er)
  Dim int2 As Integer         ' Split Data Column Counter

  ' Source Worksheet Data Extraction
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWsSource)
    If Not .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), -4123, , 1) _
        Is Nothing Then   ' Worksheet has data.
      ' Paste Source Range into Source Array
      vntSrc = .Range(cStrSourceFirst, .Cells(.Cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2) _
          .Row, .Cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column))
      ' Calculate Source Array Target Column.
      intCol = .Columns(cVntSplit).Column - .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Column + 1
     Else                 ' Worksheet is empty.
      GoTo EmptySheetErr
    End If
  End With

  ' Split Separator String into Separator Array.
  vntSep = Split(cStrSep, "|")

  ' Introduce Split Data Array
  ReDim vntSplitData(1 To UBound(vntSrc))

  ' Target Array Columns Count
  For lng1 = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
    ' Clean separators in current field of Target Column.
    vntSrc(lng1, intCol) = WorksheetFunction.trim(vntSrc(lng1, intCol))
    For int1 = 0 To UBound(vntSep)
      vntSrc(lng1, intCol) = Replace(vntSrc(lng1, intCol), _
          vntSep(int1), ",")
    Next
    ' Split current field of Target Column.
    vntSplit = Split(vntSrc(lng1, intCol), ",")
    ' Resize Target Column Array.
    If Not IsEmpty(vntCol) Then
      ReDim Preserve vntCol(1 To UBound(vntCol) + UBound(vntSplit) + 1)
     Else
      ReDim vntCol(1 To UBound(vntSplit) + 1)
    End If
    ' Copy split values to Target Column Array.
    For int1 = 0 To UBound(vntSplit)
      vntCol(UBound(vntCol) - UBound(vntSplit) + int1) = trim(vntSplit(int1))
    Next
    ' Collect Split Data.
    vntSplitData(lng1) = UBound(vntSplit) + 1
  Next

  Erase vntSplit
  Erase vntSep

  ' Write data to Target Array
  lng2 = 1
  ReDim vntTgt(1 To UBound(vntCol), 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2))
  For lng1 = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
    ' Write current row of other columns to Target Array.
    Select Case intCol
      Case 1 ' LBound(vntSrc, 2)
        For int1 = 2 To UBound(vntSrc, 2)
          vntTgt(lng2, int1) = vntSrc(lng1, int1)
        Next
      Case UBound(vntSrc, 2)
        For int1 = 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2) - 1
          vntTgt(lng2, int1) = vntSrc(lng1, int1)
        Next
      Case Else
        For int1 = 1 To intCol - 1
          vntTgt(lng2, int1) = vntSrc(lng1, int1)
        Next
        For int1 = intCol + 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2)
          vntTgt(lng2, int1) = vntSrc(lng1, int1)
        Next
    End Select
    ' Write current row of Source Array Target Column to Target Array.
    For int2 = 1 To vntSplitData(lng1)
      vntTgt(lng2, intCol) = vntCol(lng2)
      lng2 = lng2 + 1
    Next
  Next
  Erase vntCol

'  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWsTarget)
'  ' Paste Target Array into Target Worksheet.
'    .Range(cStrTargetFirst).Resize(UBound(vntTgt), UBound(vntTgt, 2)) = vntTgt
'  End With

  ' This would have been the end, if there was no formatting to do.

  ' Introducing a Range object.
  Dim objRng As Range
  Set objRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWsTarget) _
      .Range(cStrTargetFirst).Resize(UBound(vntTgt), UBound(vntTgt, 2))

'***************************************
' This is necessary if there are merged cells in the Target Range.
' This clears the whole Target Worksheet.
  objRng.Parent.Cells.Clear
' This clears only the Target Range.
'  objRng.Cells.Clear
'***************************************

  ' Paste Target Array into Target Range of  Target Worksheet.
  objRng = vntTgt
  Erase vntTgt

  With objRng
    ' Paste formatting from first row down to the last.
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count).Copy ' Copy first row.
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats        ' Paste formatting down to last.
    ' The Target Range is selected and is flickering. Therefore:
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Target Range still selected.

'***********************************************************
    ' Apply formatting (merge)
'***********************************************************

' This is up to you. I have done only some easy formatting.

'    With .Interior
'      .ColorIndex = xlNone
'      .Pattern = xlSolid
'      .PatternColorIndex
'    End With

'    ' Font
'    With .Font
'      .Name = "Verdana"
'      .Size = 10
'      .Strikethrough = False
'      .Superscript = False
'      .Subscript = False
'      .OutlineFont = False
'      .Shadow = False
'      .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
'      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'      .Bold = True
'    End With

' Borders
    With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlThin
      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlThin
      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlThin
      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlThin
      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlThin
      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlThin
      .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    lng2 = 1
    For lng1 = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
      ' Write current row of other columns to Target Array.
      Select Case intCol
        Case 1 ' LBound(vntSrc, 2)
          For int1 = 2 To UBound(vntSrc, 2): GoSub OtherFormat: Next
        Case UBound(vntSrc, 2)
          For int1 = 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2) - 1: GoSub OtherFormat: Next
        Case Else
          For int1 = 1 To intCol - 1: GoSub OtherFormat: Next
          For int1 = intCol + 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2): GoSub OtherFormat: Next
      End Select
      GoSub TargetFormat
      lng2 = lng2 + vntSplitData(lng1)
    Next

    Erase vntSplitData
    Erase vntSrc

    GoTo FormatEnd
'***********************************************************
' This is created to easily adjust (change) formatting.
' The formatting applies only to the Data range.
'***********************************************************
OtherFormat:    ' Format other columns.
  With .Cells(lng2, int1).Resize(vntSplitData(lng1))
    If vntSplitData(lng1) > 1 Then  ' Multiple rows.
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      .WrapText = False
      .Orientation = 0
      .AddIndent = False
      .IndentLevel = 0
      .ShrinkToFit = False
      .ReadingOrder = xlContext
      .MergeCells = True
     Else                           ' One row only.
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
      .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
      .WrapText = False
      .Orientation = 0
      .AddIndent = False
      .IndentLevel = 0
      .ShrinkToFit = False
      .ReadingOrder = xlContext
      .MergeCells = False
    End If
  End With
  Return
TargetFormat:   ' Format Target Column.
  With .Cells(lng2, intCol).Resize(vntSplitData(lng1))
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
  End With
  Return
FormatEnd:

    ' Only autofits the Target Range.
'    .Columns.AutoFit
    ' Autofit from top.
    .Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'***********************************************************

  End With

ProcedureExit:
  Set objRng = Nothing
Exit Sub

EmptySheetErr:
  MsgBox "You're in an empty sheet."
  GoTo ProcedureExit

End Sub
```